# Programmatically building Excel worksheet.range in C#

Tags: c#, excel

Hope you can help.

I'm looking for a way to build an excel sheet range by just passing in some parameters. My method is as follows:

```
private void TableCellformatting(int rowStart, int rowEnd, char colStart, char colEnd)
    {
        char temp;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        excelSheetRange = null;
        for (int i = rowStart; i <= rowEnd; i++)
        {
            temp = colStart;
            while (temp <= colEnd)
            {
                if (s.Length > 0)
                    s.Append(", ");
                s.Append(string.Format("{0}{1}", temp.ToString(), i));
                temp++;
            }
        }
        excelSheetRange = excelSheet.get_Range(s.ToString());
        excelSheetRange.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
    }
```

This runs ok until the excelSheet.get_Range part is called. When I pass in the cell numbers manually, I have to do it like this:

```
get_Range("A1", "A2" etc...)
```

Any ideas if this is even possible, or if there is another way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `worksheet.range` [property](https://web.archive.org/web/20150107183159/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range(v=vs.80).aspx).

```
excelSheetRange = excelSheet.Range[excelsheet.Cells[rowstart, colstart], excelsheet.Cells[rowend, colend]];
```

Comment: link is not valid anymore, do you know where I can find some Info about this? I'm confused with the fact that a `Range` variable can contain an `xlsSheet.Range[xlsSheet.Cells[rowstart, colstart]]` type but also an `xlsSheet.Range[xlsSheet.Cells[rowstart, colstart], xlsSheet.Cells[rowstart, colstart]]` variable

Comment: It is just like an overload, `xlsSheet.Range[xlsSheet.Cells[rowstart, colstart]]` == `xlsSheet.Range[xlsSheet.Cells[rowstart, colstart], xlsSheet.Cells[rowstart, colstart]]` It's like xlsSheet.Range(Cell) calls xlsSheet.Range(Cell, Cell), a `Range` is always from one `Cell` to another `Cell` a range of one cell is a unique case where the `Range` starts and stops on the same `Cell`.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150107183159/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.range(v=vs.80).aspx